Avoid hearing the carrier prompts while call rejection in twilio
I'm trying to achieve a use case in twilio, where the person A makes the call to person B without knowing the actual number of person B.
I'm using twiml.dial to make the call to person B, But in case when the person B rejects the call it goes straight away to the carrier's voicemail and it reveals the identity of person B. I tried several approaches to prevent the control going to carrier but unfortunately couldn't make it work. When the control goes to the carrier's voicemail, the call status which I receive is the ringing which makes it impossible to catch.
I'm listing the approaches which I've tried so far.
Approaches
1 . Using normal twilio call twiml.dial
2 . Using conference call
2.a Used the approach where we created conference call with user A, and did separate call to User B and when the User B accepts the call, We're trying to merge it to conference. But this made the User A left the conference abruptly.

3 . Tried the AMD detection as well but there the requirement was that phone call needs to be answered first to get the proper response.
Can anyone please guide me on this, how to approach this problem
Thanks
